# Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined error occurs only in Node environment

Tags: javascript, node.js

The following code  works fine when I try to run it in the browser JavaScript console, but it return the error below each time I try running it on qualified.io. It uses Node v6.6.0.

```
function isIsogram(word) {

  var entered = word;
  if (typeof (entered) === undefined) {
    return false
  }

  var passed = true;

  wordest = entered.toLowerCase();

  var counts = {};

  for (var i = 0; i <= wordest.length; i++) {
    var letter = wordest.toString().charAt(i)

    if (counts[letter]) {
      counts[letter] += 1
    }
    else {
      counts[letter] = 1
    }

    if (counts[letter] > 1) {
      return passed = false
    }
  }

  return passed
};

isIsogram("Altruistic");
```

Error message:

```
/home/codewarrior/mocha:16
 for (i = 0; i <= wordest.length; i++) {
                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at isIsogram (/home/codewarrior/mocha:16:27)
    at Suite.describe (/home/codewarrior/mocha:42:23)
    at Object.create (/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/interfaces/common.js:114:19)
    at context.describe.context.context (/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/interfaces/bdd.js:44:27)
    at Suite.describe (/home/codewarrior/mocha:41:5)
    at Object.create (/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/interfaces/common.js:114:19)
    at context.describe.context.context (/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/interfaces/bdd.js:44:27)
    at /home/codewarrior/mocha:40:1
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/codewarrior/mocha:64:11)
    at 
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at /.npm-global/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:222:27
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:219:14)
    at Mocha.run (/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:487:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:459:18)
    at 
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:590:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

Comment: fix your markup please

Comment: what exactly do you mean by me fixing my markup?\

Comment: Finally got the reason for the error, I was supposed to use escape(str).toLowerCase

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
escape(entered).toLowerCase()
```

instead of just using the code as is.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the value of `word` before assigning its value to `entered`.

try `if (word === undefined) { return false }` as your first line, and let me know what happens!

Comment: Why would the word ever equal the string of 'undefined'?

Comment: Either way, it looks like they might be running a test with Mocha and that's what's throwing the error. When I run the code posted (with some console logs), I get the expected output. Ah, the test might be complaining because you haven't defined the var wordest. Throw a `var` in front and rerun.

Comment: Finally got the reason for the error, I was supposed to use escape(str).toLowerCase